# Vercel cannot find multer package

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, vercel

I wrote backend code that uses the multer package tried deploying it on vercel. But I got this error screen and the following error message in the logs:

[image]

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'multer' imported from /var/task/backend/controllers/entriesController.js
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:965:9)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1022:20)
at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:876:12)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1242:79)
at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:403:12)
at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:372:25)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:249:38)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:39)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 308.35 ms    Phase: init Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'multer' imported from /var/task/backend/controllers/entriesController.js
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:965:9)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1022:20)
at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:876:12)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1242:79)
at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:403:12)
at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:372:25)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:249:38)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:39)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 417.87 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1

Here's a portion of my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase": "^9.23.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.0.0",
    "luxon": "^3.4.4",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND` indicates that Node.js is unable to find the multer package when attempting to import it in your entriesController.js file. This is likely because the multer package is not installed or is missing from your project's dependencies.

Try running from your project root: `npm install multer`

and verify that it's listed in package.json under dependencies (for example):

```
"dependencies": {
  "multer": "^1.4.5", 
  ...
}
```

You should also make sure that multer is installed under `node_modules` folder!

And last: did you try to redeploy your code to vercel?

Comment: Yes, multer is already installed. In fact, it runs normally on my local machine. I'll edit the question now to show a portion of my package.json

Comment: @vinshield you should also make sure that multer is installed under `node_modules` folder! also, did you try to redeploy to vercel?

Comment: Yes, it's installed under node_modules, I checked. And I did redeploy